# struct with a pointer inside that is an array (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have the following struct:

```
struct card{
  int id;
  int *products_id;
  int number;}
```

The thing that the pointer products_id must be an array because i need to save different products id for the same id. I want to know how to declare and use this array. Also how can i save the data i need inside of it.

Comment: add some memory for an array with malloc (and probably an int size, to remember the size)

Comment: Time to learn what [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) is, and [how to access struct elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)).

Comment: Also, it's fairly common just to make a fixed size array of the MAX needed, and just waste the unused space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct card{
  int id;
  int *products_id;
  int number;
};


int main ()
{
    struct card c;
    c.products_id = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*3); // 3 ints
    c.products_id[0] = 3;
    c.products_id[1] = 4;
    c.products_id[2] = 5;

    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d\n", c.products_id[i]);
    }
}
```

Output

```
$ ./a.out 
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store products id inside this struct declare array

```
int products_id[MAX_PRODUCTS_ID];
```

Pointer `*products_id` can store an address of outside memory (that you should manage by yourself)